# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mid a_n + 3(\frac{n-2}{n})^n \mid^{\frac1n} = \frac35$. Then find $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mid a_n + 3(\frac{n-2}{n})^n \mid^{\frac1n} = \frac35$$

Then find  $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$.

Tried very hard yet not able to crack it. Help Needed.

Anyone able to do the sum??

Comment: Note that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\tfrac{2}{n}\right)^n=e^{-2}$.

Comment: Correct, I will make the change. Thanks.

Comment: @Dr.MV From this observation alone, $a_n$ has no (finite) limit. Statement "$a_n \to \infty$" is stronger than that and needs additional proof.

Comment: @Dr.MV If $a_n = (\frac{3}{5})^n - 3(1-\frac{2}{n})^{n}$, then $a_n \to -3e^{-2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $b_n$ be the sequence given $b_n=a_n+3\left(1-\frac2n\right)^n$.  So, if $\lim_{n\to \infty}|b_n|^{1/n}=3/5$, then for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists a number $N$ such that for all $n>N$

$$\left(\frac35-\epsilon\right)<|b_n|^{1/n}<\left(\frac35+\epsilon\right) \tag 1$$

For $0<\epsilon<2/5$, the inequalities in $(1)$ are equivalent to

$$\left(\frac35-\epsilon\right)^n<|b_n|<\left(\frac35+\epsilon\right)^n \tag 2$$

Letting $n\to \infty$, the squeeze theorem guarantees that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}|b_n|=0\implies \lim_{n\to \infty}b_n=0\tag3$$

Inasmuch as $b_n=a_n+3\left(1-\frac2n\right)^n$, we see from $(3)$ that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=-\lim_{n\to \infty}3\left(1-\frac2n\right)^n=-3/e^2$$

And we are done!