# What is the value of lim$_{n\to \infty} a_n$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|a_n+ 3\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^n \right|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{3}{5}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers such that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left|a_n+ 3\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^n \right|^{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{3}{5}.$$

What is the value of $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$?

Comment: I edited your question. Some LaTeX tips: you can use \{ \} inside math mode (i.e., inside the $ signs) to make braces. You can use \lim to make the limit symbol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mid a_n + 3(\frac{n-2}{n})^n \mid^{\frac1n} = \frac35$. Then find $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862326/lim-n-to-infty-mid-a-n-3-fracn-2nn-mid-frac1n-frac35-th)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have $$\lim_{n \to \infty}|a_n+ 3((n-2)/n)^n|^{1/n}=3/5 <1.$$ So by the root test, the series $\sum|(a_n+ 3((n-2)/n)^n|$ converges, therefore the general term converges to $0$.

Note that:

$$((n-2)/n)^n = (1-2/n)^n \to e^{-2}$$

This shows that $a_n \to -3e^{-2}$.

Comment: @Dr.MV when a series converges, its general term goes to $0$

Comment: Yes, I know.  But we need not use results from series analysis when analyzing a sequence.

Comment: @Dr.MV but then we have to basically prove that thing (which you did in your answer)

Comment: Your proof is fine.  It's quite possible that the OP and others who are in the middle of studying sequences have not yet studied series.  They would not have, therefore, the requisite tools to apply this approach.  That is the reason that I took a "back to basics" approach.

Comment: Good approach+1.

Answer (score 6):

If $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}\left|a_n+ 3\left(1-\frac2n\right)^n\right|^{1/n}=3/5$, then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists a number $N(\epsilon)$ such that

$$\frac35-\epsilon\le\left|a_n+ 3\left(1-\frac2n\right)^n\right|^{1/n}<\frac35+\epsilon \tag 1$$

whenever $n>N(\epsilon)$.  The inequality in $(1)$ is equivalent to the inequality

$$\left(\frac35-\epsilon\right)^n\le \left|a_n+ 3\left(1-\frac2n\right)^n\right|\le \left(\frac35+\epsilon\right)^n \tag 2$$

for $n>N(\epsilon)$.

Since $(2)$ is true for all $\epsilon$, it is true for $\epsilon\le r<\frac25$.  Letting $n\to \infty$ in $(2)$ for such $\epsilon$, we see that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left|a_n+ 3\left(1-\frac2n\right)^n\right|=0.$$

Since the absolute value function is continuous, we must have

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(a_n+ 3\left(1-\frac2n\right)^n\right)=0,$$

which implies

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=-\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(3\left(1-\frac2n\right)^n\right)=-3e^{-2}.$$

And we are done!

Comment: You are basically proving the known result I used in my answer (+1)

Comment: @OpenBall Thank you for the "up vote!"  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}3\left(\frac{n-2}{n}\right)^n=3e^{-2}$$

$$\implies \lim_{n \to\infty}a_n=-3e^{-2}$$

since $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^n=0.$$

Comment: that is very clean.............+1

Comment: @Bhaskara-III Thanks a lot for your comment.